# Add event time to the day - Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In calendar, dates are fetched from the database and displayed onto the calendar as follows:

```
var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2014, 8, 1),
        end: new Date(2014, 8, 3),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2014, 9, 2),
        allDay: true}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        events: events_array
    })

});
```

My question is how can I add the event timing when fetched from the database? is there something like new Time for example as to avoid conflict when having multiple events per day?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I add the event timing when fetched from the database?

What do you mean by 'event timing' ?

> is there something like new Time for example as to avoid conflict when having multiple events per day?

You can have multiple events in the same day with the same hour, time, duration, etc, as long as their id's are different or null, they are treated as individual events, so there should not be any conflicts regarding dates.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to display the timing of each one in the day. For example, 1:00 pm event, 4:30 event...etc.
I have figured out how this can be done as follows:

```
eventsArray.push({title: "{{$e->event_name}}", 
                start: new Date(start.substring(0,4),start.substring(5,7)-1, start.substring(8,10),
                    startTime.substring(0,2), startTime.substring(3,5)),
                end: new Date(end.substring(0,4),end.substring(5,7)-1, end.substring(8,10),
                    endTime.substring(0,2)-2, endTime.substring(3,5)),
                url: "events/"+eventID});
```

Hours and minutes can be added to the new Date array and displayed correctly.